# Fordwarding all incoming traffic to a specific dest IP through OpenVPN tap0 interface

Tags: networking, debian, routing, ipv4, pfsense

Can anybody help me out on how I am supposed to make sure, my VPS accepts all traffic to 1.1.1.1/30 (sample IP) and forwards it to my pfSense instance?

**I've got the following setting:**

- I have a VPS with a publicly routable /32 IPv4 (let's say 1.2.3.4/32) as well as publicly routable /30 IPv4 (let's say 1.1.1.1/30)
- The 1.2.3.4/32 is the IP on interface `ens18`, my ISP routes the 1.1.1.1/30 subnet over the same interface
- When I add any IP within the 1.1.1.1/30 to `lo` or `ens18` interface, those are publicly reachable (pingable)
- My home firewall (FreeBSD based pfSense) is connected to the VPS via OpenVPN tap (`ovpnc3` interface)
- I have added a static route on the VPS: `ip route add 1.1.1.1/30 dev tap0`
- `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` is set on the VPS
- I have added the following firewall rules on the VPS:
- - `iptables -I FORWARD -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 1.1.1.1/30 -j ACCEPT`
- - `iptables -I FORWARD -s 1.1.1.1/30 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT`

The VPS runs on Debian 11 (bullseye) and the home firewall on pfSense 23.05.1-RELEASE (FreeBSD 14.0)

**What I achieved so far:**

- When I add 1.1.1.1/32 as an alias to the `ovpnc3` interface, I get replies via both `arping` and `ping` from pfSense from the VPS (via SSH)
- Pinging through a phsyical interface on the pfSense instance works as well
- But incoming traffic from the outside world (public internet) results in 100% packet loss

**What I want to achieve:**

- All traffic to the entire 1.1.1.1/30 should be forwarded to the pfSense over the OpenVPN tunnel

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about the role of each described interface (especially: what is the difference between tap0 and ovpnc3? are they the two ends of the VPN, tap0 on Debian, ovpnc3 on FreeBSD?) Did you verify using tcpdump on both systems and on each of their interfaces, where the traffic disappears? Added routes on pfSense? Also, if pfSense has its own Internet access, how will it handle sending a packet to, say, 192.0.2.2 once from its direct Internet access, and again using the VPN (from 1.1.1.1)? This usually requires policy routing. if SRPF is enabled, incoming packets are usually dropped.

Comment: SRPF: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.2 . The drop would happen on pfSense. But I don't know much about FreeBSD/pfSense. Still tcpdump would tell if: it's routed in the VPN by Debian, and if yes, if there's a reply or not from pfSense, and if this reply is routed back in the VPN or using the direct Internet access (and be very quickly dropped by an upstream router because of SRPF or lost because of NAT and a wrong source address).

Comment: (and my bad, the interface roles were correctly described)

Comment: I did try `tcpdump` on the VPS on both the `ens18` and `tap0` interfaces and pinged from both the VPS and from a completely independent network (via mobile data and HE.net tools app). It indeed seems like both pings are sent over the `tap0` interface to pfSense. The drop indeed happens on the pfSense router for some reason as only the ping sent via external network shows "[Expert Info (Warning/Sequence): No response seen to ICMP request]". The packets are indeed sent via the `tap0` interface (OpenVPN)

Comment: So it's what I said: the main problem is routing on pfSense, not on Debian. pfSense becomes [dual-homed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming): two possible routes to Internet. Alas, I don't have much knowledge on how to do [policy routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) on FreeBSD.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you remove the normal (non-VPN) default route on pfSense, keeping only the route to 1.2.3.4/32 through the non-VPN interface to allow only the VPN to be established, you'll make pfSense not multi-homed anymore, with its single default route throught the VPN, allowing this to work as a proof of concept.

Comment: When I change the default route to go through the VPN, pinging works indeed. So your hunch seems to be correct. However, pinging from pfSense to e.g. Google DNS fails now instead. The best way to avoid this would be some form of source-based routing, or to have a second dedicated routing table for the tap interface. But source based routing requires multiple routing tables, if I understand it correctly. And that apparently requires me to recompile the BSD kernel on pfSense with some flags set..

Comment: As I noticed a short while ago, pfSense ended support for their free pfSense+ Home/Lab and I haven’t gotten any software updates in ages, so I was planning on moving away from pfSense anyways. So maybe I should give Debian-based VyOS a try. Do you have any hints or suggestions on how to enable source based routing on Linux, or a Debian flavor specifically?

Comment: Each OS works differently. Search how FreeBSD handles source-based routing (it's policy routing). From wikipedia, `pf` is one tool to handle this ( "FreeBSD supports PBR using either IPFW, IPFilter or OpenBSD's PF. "). Why use VyOS if you're looking to type commands? Either have a tool that can handle this with its own ways (and a GUI) or use a plain OS and do it yourself. So Search if VyOS can do this first. See also: https://support.vyos.io/en/support/solutions/articles/103000096259-is-it-free-to-use-vyos-

Comment: For Linux, search on unix SE, SU or SF and also include in the search "ip rule" (in addition to other keywords: multihomed, vpn ...), that's a good way to find Q/A about policy routing on Linux.